# Matching a repeated group separated by pipe

Tags: regex, regex-group

Here is my text:

```
"cn=AAAA,ou=Profils,o=SF|cn=BBBB,ou=Profils,o=SF"
"cn=CCCC,ou=Profils,o=SF"
```

And here is my RegEx:

```
"cn=([A-Z]{4}),.*(\|cn=([A-Z0-9]{4}),.*)"
```

I want to extract what is after `cn=`, so, here `AAAA`, `BBBB` and `CCCC`.
The second line does not match.

Here is my [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Xvct56/1/)

Comment: Do you mean `\bcn=([A-Z]{4})` ? https://regex101.com/r/z2lUKX/1

Comment: If you want 2 capturing groups, you could make the second part optional `"cn=([A-Z]{4})[^|\r\n]*(?:\|cn=([A-Z0-9]{4})[^|\r\n]*)?"` https://regex101.com/r/uXXebn/1

Comment: Did you meant to include `CCCC` in your wanted results? Because in that same line you say that the second sentence **should not match**? So that would tell me that you only want `AAAA` and `BBBB` because that line has a pipe symbol. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract AAAA, BBBB or CCCC, wouldn't just "([A-Z]{4})" in this case suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `\bcn=([A-Z]{4})\b`

Explanation:

`\b` - word boundary

`cn=` - match `cn=` literally

`(...)` - first capturing group

`[A-Z]{4}` - match uppercase letter four times

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vKFR5t/2)

Text you want to extract is in first captuirng group

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to assume the length or type of the match (that is, just match anything up to the next comma):

```
\bcn=([^,]*)
```

1. `\b` Match a word boundary.
2. `cn=' Match "cn=".
3. `([,]*)` Capture in capture group #1 zero or more non-comma characters (until you get to the comma).

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9NHdP1/2/)